# React native sound mutes user music (Spotify, deezer, etc.)

Tags: react-native, react-native-sound

With [react-native-background-timer (2.4.1)](https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer) and [react-native-sound (0.11.1)](https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound), I play a sound after countdown.

```
import Sound from 'react-native-sound'
...
Sound.setCategory('Playback')
const soundEnd = new Sound('training.mp3', Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE)

...

const playBackgroundTimer = useCallback(
  (timeInSeconds) => {
    const timeoutId = BackgroundTimer.setTimeout(() => {
      soundEnd.play(() => {})
    }, (1000 * timeInSeconds) - 5000)

    return timeoutId
  },
  []
)
```

The countdown countdown sound (just a five second beep) permanently mutes the user's music (Deezer, Spotify, etc.).

Ideally, I would like the user's music to drop in volume, and if not possible for it to continue after the countdown.

Do you have a solution ?